# Using SQL-Server how to query all live/active projects from TFS

Tags: sql-server, tfs, azure-devops

I am trying to query every live project name and request from TFS on the Microsoft SQL Server Management studio.
The issue I am having is when I try to it shows previous versions of project parts. An example is that I had a project with a request called "Change this name". After a few weeks, the request name was changed to "New Name"
When I run my query I get both "Change this name" and  "New Name"

```
Select Distinct   *
FROM Tfs_Warehouse.dbo.FactCurrentWorkItem FCWI

INNER join Tfs_Warehouse.dbo.DimTeamProject TP
ON  FCWI.TeamProjectSK = TP.ProjectNodeSK
INNER JOIN Tfs_Warehouse.dbo.DimWorkItem wi
        ON TP.ProjectNodeSK = wi.TeamProjectSK
```

Every form I am using says to use FactCurrentWrokItem for live events but I still get the history of a project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really hate that this is the solution but
If you `System_RevisedDate = '9999-01-01 00:00:00.000'`
from `Tfs_Warehouse.dbo.DimTeamProject`, this date means that this is the live and newest version.